# Custom submit function after jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, form-submit

How would I add a custom submit function to a form to prevent it's normal action but so that it only runs after being validated by the jQuery Validation plugin?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`submitHandler`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) option of [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options), like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //this runs when the form validated successfully
    form.submit(); //submit it the form
  }
});
```

There's also an `invalidHandler` if you want to run something when it *doesn't* pass validation.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler `return true` to proceed and `return false` to stop.

Comment: There's no need to `return true` in any cases, `return false` is special, but an `undefined` (no return) will continue as well.